# Freeing dynamically allocated char* in method C/C++

Tags: c++

Assuming I have code like this:

```
char* Complex::getString(void)
{   
        char *p;
        int n = snprintf( NULL, 0, "%.6f+%.6fi", (float)_re, (float)_im);
        p = (char*)malloc(n+1);
        sprintf( p,  "%.6f+%.6fi", (float)_re, (float)_im);

        return p;
}
```

Should I free p, and if yes - where and why?

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? They're different languages, with very different memory management facilities. (I guess from the `::` that you're writing C++, but ignoring all the features that make code easy to write).

Comment: Return an `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`, problem solved.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: what difference does it make in this case? None !

Comment: @user1233963: In C++, you would return `std::string`, or some other type that automatically manages the allocated memory, and remove all scope for ambiguity. In C, the only option is manual pointer-juggling and careful documentation.

Comment: Please make your mind up about which language you are using and tag the question accordingly.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: that is totally not related to the question

Comment: @user1233963 the difference is having to track raw pointers and who is owning the memory and lots of other stuff C++ classes could automatically take care of.

Comment: @user1233963 It's well accepted around here that you should tag the question for the language that you are actually using.

Comment: @user1233963 of course it is. C++ allows you to side-step the problem completely.

Comment: @juanchopanza: that is still not an answer to THIS question. It's a workaround.

Comment: @user1233963: It's not a "workaround"; it's how you would write this function in C++ if you didn't want to spend your life debugging memory leaks. There's no indication in the question that nasty C-style pointer manipulation is a requirement, or that the function can't be changed to return a more friendly type.

Comment: @user1233963 It is a perfectly valid answer. Any other answer would be encouraging people to write crap C++.

Comment: I'm starting the C++ adventure and just didn't know how to do it with all advantages of the language. I needed classes, but decided to code "core" functionality of the method in C. I know there are dozens of easier solutions using C++ but I just wanted to ask about freeing the C pointer. Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: @KerrekSB, if `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` is used, then would it then be required to replace the `malloc` with a `new[]`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: naturally :-) Or use a version with a custom deleter...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're writing C With Classes, then you'll have to document that the caller is responsible for freeing the memory. It can't be freed within this function, since you're returning a pointer to it.

If you're writing C++, then life's too short for messing around with raw pointers. Return a `std::string` so that the memory is managed automatically.

Comment: And if you malloc a temporary char array, only to return a std::string, you'll need to free that array within the function!

Comment: "life's too short for messing around with raw pointers" so true :) +1

Comment: Thanks Mike, this is a great answer. My question now is - what happens if I don't free the memory using the caller?

Comment: @SzymonFortuna: If you don't free it, then it's leaked. If you keep leaking memory, then eventually you'll run out and the program will (probably) crash.

Answer (score 3):

If you `malloc` something you should consider freeing it, otherwise you have a leak.
Where? Well, not inside the function since the return value will be no use to the caller. The caller will have to take control of the pointer and free it when they are finished. This will make it hard to write exception safe code.

Of course, if you changed the function signature to return a `std::string` you would avoid all these questions/problems.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you should rather change signature of your function to return `std:string`:

```
std::string Complex::getString(void);
```

And your problem is gone.

Instead of `snprintf` use `std::stringstream`.

If you want to use `malloc`, which is not recommended in a C++ program in any case, then obviously the responsibility for releasing the memory is with the caller. Your function cannot release the memory allocated for your string before returning it to the caller. You should document this so users know they have to do. But users of your code (including yourself) will often forget about it and memory will leak. Also, the client code gets more convoluted in this case, which is not great.

Answer (score 1):

You should free the pointer returned by the function Complex::getString in the function caller code, when you don't need no more that pointer.